# Make git run as a different user

Tags: linux, git

Is there a way to enable git to use specific users on the system when running as root on a per repo basis?

Repo1 when run as root files would be owned by 1000

Repo2 when run as root files would be owned by 2000

and so on..

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  This sounds like you should have a script.  You can always run as another user with `su - someuser -c "/somecommand.sh"`.  Alternatively, use `sudo` as it might be a better fit for your problem.

Comment: @Jefromi I'm trying to make all the files owned by 1000 instead of root, when Git creates new files from a pull or merge.

Comment: So the question then is... why are you unnecessarily running as root instead of that user?

Comment: @Jefromi - I could su into 1000, but I'm looking for a way that git would handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You could have a local wrapper for git that would add this behaviour in the path ahead of the normal tools, though, which might better achieve your goals.

Comment: Or you could just switch users. Running things unnecessarily as root is kind of asking for trouble.